Issues using SAP Table Connector in ADF with SHIR
Hi I am attempting to use the SAP Table connector in ADF, I have put in all credentials correctly.
However, when I test connection, this is the error that I get !
"Could not load file or assembly 'sapnco_utils, Version=3.1.0.42, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=50436dca5c7f7d23' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."
I have tried installing both SAP .NET Connector 3.0 and SAP .NET Connector 3.1 .
Previously I was getting the error
""Assembly 'sapnco, Version=3.0.0.42, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=50436dca5c7f7d23' was not found in the GAC. Verify that 'Install assemblies in GAC' was selected while installing the SAP .NET Connector."
which got resolved after I reinstalled with SAP .NET Connector 3.0, as I was not able to see the "Install assemblies in GAC" option while using the SAP .NET Connector 3.1.
I am quite confused on this, so any help ?


"Could not load file or assembly 'sapnco_utils, Version=3.1.0.42, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=50436dca5c7f7d23' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

According to this MS document
When the On-Premises Data Gateway is unable to find NCo 3.1 then above error. To resolve this error Install NCo 3.1 from SAP.

Install assemblies in GAC" option while using the SAP .NET Connector 3.1


Download the 64-bit  SAP Connector for Microsoft .NET 3.0  from SAP's website, and install it on the self-hosted integration runtime machine. During installation, make sure you select the  Install Assemblies to GAC  option in the  Optional setup steps  window.



For more information you can refer to the MS document.
